# Ansible: Speed up a find and link file

Tags: ansible

Currently, I'm using the code to link the binaries files in some directories to `/usr/local/bin`

```
- name: Find the files to link in /usr/local/bin
  find:
    paths:
      - "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/"
      - "/usr/local/java/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin"
  register: usrlocalbinfiles

- name: Link SDK files
  file:
    src: "{{item.path}}"
    dest: "/usr/local/bin/{{item.path|basename}}"
    state: link
  with_items: "{{usrlocalbinfiles.files}}"
  become: yes
```

If I check the execution of a playbook with this code and the debug option (-vvv) I see that ansible connect to the remote host with each item in the list. My `~/.ansible.cfg` has the next options to enable the shared ssh connection

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
become=True
become_method='su'

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args=-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=120s -o ControlPath=/tmp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

Is it possible to speed up the playbook that uses this code? The problem is the loop that uses `with_item`: A connection using ssh per item.

Answer (score 1):

Add also

```
[ssh_connection]    
pipelining = true
```

If you see several ssh calls, then pipelining is NOT in use. If there is single `ssh` call:

```
SSH: EXEC ssh ... python && sleep 0
```

Then pipelining is working.